# How we can invoke PCF(Nodejs service) service from C# application?

Tags: c#, node.js

We have Nodejs service which is deployed in PCF. Now we have to invoke this service from C# application(.NET application). So could you please help us to find out exact steps, how we can achieve this functionality.

thanks

Comment: Presuming the PCF service exposes an endpoint or is listening to a queue/topic, the .NET app would just need to make an http call or publish a message.

Answer (score 0):

NodejS service deployed in PCF must be exposed via web URL so I think it means making a web API call from .net client as detailed [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)